# using HTTPHandler cause Django server side shows http 400 and Invalid HTTP_HOST header message

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am using [HTTPHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#httphandler) to send logging messages to a Django Web server with The following code,

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

_TARGET = '192.168.8.100:8000'
_PATH = '/VideoParser/lYYDownloaderClientLog/'

sh = logging.handlers.HTTPHandler(_TARGET, _PATH)

logger.addHandler(sh)
logger.error('testing remote logging')
```

but The server side shows http 400 and Invalid HTTP_HOST header message like this

> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '192.168.8.100:8000,192.168.8.100'. The
>   domain name pr ovided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.
>   [05/Apr/2017 10:43:14] "GET
>   /VideoParser/lYYDownloaderClientLog/?relativeCreated
>   =117.00654029846191&thread=5468&levelname=ERROR&exc_info=None&exc_text=None&proc
>   ess=8920&filename=a.py&msecs=39.52503204345703&stack_info=None&levelno=40&proces
>   sName=MainProcess&msg=testing+remote+logging&module=a&threadName=MainThread&line
>   no=26&created=1491360192.039525&funcName=%3Cmodule%3E&args=%28%29&name=**main**&
>   pathname=C%3A%5CUsers%5Ci%5CDocuments%5CTencent+Files%5C2281570025%5CFileRecv%5C
>   a.py HTTP/1.1" 400 68137

while request from browser with url

> http://192.168.8.100:8000/VideoParser/lYYDownloaderClientLog/?filename=log55.p%20y&levelno=40&relativeCreated=88.00482749938965&funcName=%3Cmodule%3E&thread=7144%20&stack_info=None&module=log55&args=%28%29&exc_text=None&pathname=D%3A%5CBaiduYun%20Download%5C%E7%BC%96%E7%A8%8B%5CPython%5Clog55.py&levelname=ERROR&msecs=668.0548%20191070557&threadName=MainThread&process=6664&name=root&lineno=34&msg=yahoo+Serve%20r+Exception&exc_info=None&processName=MainProcess&created=1491225161.6680548

could actually send a good request to The server , The server shows The following in this case

```
----666666666666--- <QueryDict: {'stack_info': ['None'], 'levelno': ['40'], 'arg
s': ['()'], 'exc_info': ['None'], 'created': ['1491225161.6680548'], 'process':
['6664'], 'levelname': ['ERROR'], 'exc_text': ['None'], 'module': ['log55'], 'ms
ecs': ['668.0548 191070557'], 'name': ['root'], 'processName': ['MainProcess'],
'lineno': ['34'], 'thread': ['7144 '], 'msg': ['yahoo Serve r Exception'], 'func
Name': ['<module>'], 'threadName': ['MainThread'], 'filename': ['log55.p y'], 'p
athname': ['D:\\BaiduYun Download\\编程\\Python\\log55.py'], 'relativeCreated':
['88.00482749938965']}>
[05/Apr/2017 10:45:26] "GET /VideoParser/lYYDownloaderClientLog/?filename=log55.
p%20y&levelno=40&relativeCreated=88.00482749938965&funcName=%3Cmodule%3E&thread=
7144%20&stack_info=None&module=log55&args=%28%29&exc_text=None&pathname=D%3A%5CB
aiduYun%20Download%5C%E7%BC%96%E7%A8%8B%5CPython%5Clog55.py&levelname=ERROR&msec
s=668.0548%20191070557&threadName=MainThread&process=6664&name=root&lineno=34&ms
g=yahoo+Serve%20r+Exception&exc_info=None&processName=MainProcess&created=149122
5161.6680548 HTTP/1.1" 200 27
```

so what's wrong with my code using [HTTPHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#httphandler) to send logging messages to a Django Web server  ?

As I have tested: If I pass the IP address of my web server to the host parameter of HTTPHandler, the server side would show http 400 and Invalid HTTP_HOST header message, there are also exceptions , pasted here https://bpaste.net/show/f2d2e64e7a7e , while if I pass the domain name instead, then the view function works as expected . 
so would it be a bug within HTTPHandler?

related code For debug

django-test\LYYDownloaderServer\VideoParser\urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
app_name = 'VideoParser'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'lYYDownloaderClientLog.+',views.lYYDownloaderClientLog, name='lYYDownloaderClientLog')
]
```

django-test\LYYDownloaderServer\VideoParser\views.py

```
def lYYDownloaderClientLog(request):
    print('----666666666666---', request.GET)
    return HttpResponse("")  # The server *successfully* processed the request and is not returning any content.
```

Comment: Looks like the domain name is wrong. Did you type it right?

Comment: @LeonardoChirivì sorry for that, I updated with the corresponding sever message this time.

Comment: is 192.168.8.100 added to allowed_host?

Comment: @LeonardoChirivì added, but the issue remains ,I usual give ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem when I use Django receive log, finally I dont solve it, but i known the problem is.

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:8888,127.0.0.1'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.
```

according to the output, I check the source code of `logging.handlers.HTTPHandler`, and in this class, function `emit` will instance `http.client.HTTPSConnection` or `http.client.HTTPConnection` then execute `putrequest` and `putheader`, but in the `putrequest` will execute `putheader` to, because the port != 80, the host is `host:port`

```
                if port == self.default_port:
                    self.putheader('Host', host_enc)
                else:
                    host_enc = host_enc.decode("ascii")
                    self.putheader('Host', "%s:%s" % (host_enc, port))
```

so I guess if you use Nginx and 80 port, maybe you can resolve the problem

update:
Finally I resolve it. I make a new class `LogHTTPHandler`, inherit the HTTPHandler, then rewrite the function `emit` and comment out `h.putheader("Host", host)`

```
from logging.handlers import HTTPHandler

class LogHTTPHandler(HTTPHandler):
    def emit(self, record):
        ......
        i = host.find(":")
        if i >= 0:
            host = host[:i]
        # h.putheader("Host", host)
        if self.method == "POST":
            h.putheader("Content-type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            h.putheader("Content-length", str(len(data)))
        ......
```

Comment: Great investigation ! I used to test the program on my local machine , so raised the error message , but when I tested it on a remote server which run s on nginx/1.4.4, no error message at all, so maybe you got the right point. If this was a bug in Python , please report it, thanks !